# Change key value in for loop, regardless of the current value in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm running a for loop on a dictionary, and I need to alter the Key if it starts with "C-" to a specific string, regardless on what follows after the C-

Sample data:

```
 {'H-NSW-BAC-ENG': 15, 'C-NSW-BAC-ENG': 15, 'H-NSW-BAC-FBE': 30, 'C-NSW-BAC-FBE': 30, 'G-NSW-BAC-ENG': 15, 'G-NSW-BAC-FBE': 30}
```

Method I'm using to do so:

```
def transform_caps_keys(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if k[0:1] == 'C':
            k = "C-STD-B&M-SUM"
            print(k)
    print(d)
```

I need 'C-NSW-BAC-ENG' and 'C-NSW-BAC-FBE' to be changed to 'C-STD-B&M-SUM'.

When I print k, I get the keys I want, but they are not changed within the dictionary.

I also tried:

```
def transform_caps_keys(d):
for k, v in d.items():
    if k[0:1] == 'C':
        d['C-STD-B&M-SUM'] = d.pop(k)
        print(k)
print(d)
```

But I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Comment: You can create a new dictionary. The problem is you cannot have two identical keys in a dictionary so you'll have only one element with the key `'C-STD-B&M-SUM'` in your new dict.

Comment: Is there a way to sum the values from all the keys that are repeated? They are all integers.

Comment: I mean the values from the keys that are 'C-STD-B&M-SUM', not from all the keys.

Comment: You  can sum the values of the keys which beginn with `'C'` in your old dict.

Comment: Got it, thanks! I'll just sum the values, create a new key and delete the old ones.

Comment: Do not iterate d.items() make a list like z=list(d.keys()) and iterate that

Answer (score 1):

You cannot alter an iterable collection while iterating it (the keys collection), moreover - any "edit" over a key in a dictionary means a new key in that dictionary, long story short you'll need a new dictionary based on your altering rules.

Answer (score 0):

```
    def transform_caps_keys(d):
        for k, v in d.items():
            if k[0:1] == 'C':
                val = "C-STD-B&M-SUM"
                d[val] = d[k]
                del d[k]
        print(d)
```